# how to handle lengthy label on x-axis in jpgraph when it is rotated 90 degree.

Tags: php, jpgraph

I have made a horizontal bar graph using `jpgraph`, and rotated it 90 degrees. But the label on x-axis is being cut off, i.e not shown whole label.
I have set `$graph->theme = null;`
and also set margin. But nothing changes.

Please suggest me way to handle it.
For example I have a label `Business management & Administration` on x-axis.

Comment: How did you get your barchart to display horizontal? I followed documentation but `$graph->Set90AndMargin()` doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a new line to the labels so it is shorter and adjusting the margins via `$graph->Set90AndMargin(a,b,c,d);` The margins can be a little confusing, the top margin (ie c) also rotates with the graph so you are now adjusting the right margin, if that makes sense.